# SMA Get-AutomationVariable bug

Tags: powershell, service, automation

We're experiencing a very annoying bug in our Service Manager Automation (SMA) environment.
The command 'Get-AutomationVariable' returns nothing when it's enclosed in parenthesis...

Has anyone run into the same problem?

```
workflow Start-TestWorkflow
{
    $Stage = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SMAStage'
    $ModulePath = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ModulePath'
    $Stage
    $ModulePath
    "---------------------"
    $Stage2 = (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SMAStage')
    $ModulePath2 = (Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ModulePath')
    $Stage2
    $ModulePath2
}
```

Output:

```
PROD 
\\contoso.com\dfs\Applications\SMAS\PROD\Modules
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question got answered on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a89c1be-f783-4f6e-98b0-1c1775009723/sma-bug-getautomationvariable?forum=scogeneral) by *Craig A McDonald*:

> So, after some testing, wrapping an expression in parentheses causes
>   it to get run by PowerShell just like when you call InlineScript. You
>   are getting $null returned as it does not know anything about
>   Get-AutomationVariable. Makes sense but is the first time I have seen
>   it.